# How can I add custom markup with a theme function?

Tags: forms

I have a simple form as follows

```
function MY_MODULE_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['MY_MODULE']['message'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => 'My Heading',
    '#tree' => true,
  return $form;
}
```

But I want the markup to change depending on some factor which will be defined inside a function.

So how would I call a function to do this for the #markup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this the drupal way, you should use a theme function:

```
function MY_MODULE_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['MY_MODULE']['message'] = array(
    '#theme'    => 'mymodule_markup',
    '#var1'     => $var1,
    '#var2'     => $var2,
  );
  return $form;
}
```

Then implement hook_theme:

```
function MY_MODULE_theme() {
return array(
  'mymodule_markup' => array(
    'variables' => array('var1' => NULL, 'var2'=>NULL),
  ),
);
```

}

Then implement your theme function

```
function theme_mymodule_markup($var1, $var2) {
    return 'some string';
}
```

You also could use a template to render your markup. That way themers can overwrite your markup without having to dig into your module files.

Comment: awesome thanks, really helped me learn and understand this

Comment: Glad I could help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try following:

```
function MY_MODULE_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['MY_MODULE']['message'] = array(
    '#type'    => 'markup',
    '#markup'  => some_custom_function(),
    '#tree'    => true,
  );
  return $form;
}

function some_custom_function() {
    return "Test string";
}
```